# Remove the # character from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have a `js-slider` and it's url is changed every time, when changes pictures.
I want to remove `/#/` from url.

```
document.location.href = String( document.location.href ).replace( "#/", "");
```

It's work, but plugin `jquery.address.js` doesn't view page and  redirected to 403.
How can I remove this symbol and the slider would work.

site: http://taron-julhakyan.ru

Thankes!!!

Comment: You just want to remove `#/` from URL or with `#/` text following it?

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle with the js-slider? Maybe you can just remove the `#` there where you click the button. Then it will never appear in the URL ... simpler, cleaner, better

Comment: are you using angular?

Comment: site http://taron-julhakyan.ru/ . I whant delete this 2 simbol '#/'

Comment: Sherlock, I can delete this simble, After that the slider does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp in javascript

```
document.location.href = document.location.href.replace(**/(#)[0-9A-Za-z-]+/ig, "#/"**);
```

Here the /ig suffix says that the regex is case **i**nsensitive and and **g**lobal stating.

For more information refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)